# Why do we need to show equality exists for finding maxima/minima questions?

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I solved the following question using AM-GM inequality while practicing in an app

"If $x,y,z$ are positive real numbers satisfying $xyz=32$, find the minimum value of:

$$x^2+4xy+4y^2+2z^2$$

In the question discussion, many people commented that we must show equality exists for the maxima/minima.

Why do we need to?

Sorry for my poor english.
Thank you.

Comment: As a silly example, I know that $x^2+4 \geq 0$, but this does not imply that the minimum value of $x^2+4$ is actually $0$. I know that the minimum value is $4$ because (a) $x^2+4 \geq 4$ for all $x$ and (b) there actually exists $x$ (namely $x=0$) such that $x^2+4=4$.

Comment: For example, if for some $m$, $f(x, y, z)=x^2+4xy+4y^2+2z^2\geq m$ for all $x, y, z$ subject to the constraint $xyz=32$, then we can not say that $m$ is the minimum value of $f(x, y, z)$. If $f(x, y, z) \geq m+1$ also, then $m$ is certainly not the minimum, but we can say $m$ is a lower bound. Moreover, if $f(x, y, z) \geq m$ and $m$ is the largest lower bound, then $m$ is still not necessarily the minimum, as $f(x, y, z)$ may approach $m$ but may never reach it.

Comment: I think that what they $meant$ to say is that if we prove only that $96$ is the greatest lower bound (glb) for the set of values of $f(x,y,z)$, then that does not imply that $96$ is the minimum value because we have not  shown that there exist $x,y,z$ such that $f(x,y,z)=96$. In English,$ \min S$ is the smallest $member$ of $S$ (if there is one). Example: Let $g(x,y)=x^2+(xy-1)^2$ for real $x,y$. Then $g$ has no minimum value  but $g$ can be as close to $0$ as you  want.

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM twice we obtain:
$$x^2+4xy+4y^2+2z^2=(x+2y)^2+2z^2\geq(2\sqrt{2xy})^2+2z^2=8xy+2z^2=$$
$$=4xy+4xy+2z^2\geq3\sqrt{(4xy)^2\cdot2z^2}=96.$$
The equality occurs for $x=2y$, $2xy=z^2$ and $xyz=32$ or $(x,y,z)=(4,2,4),$ which says that we got a minimal value.

Indeed, $$4^2+4\cdot4\cdot2+4\cdot2^2+2\cdot4^2=96,$$ which is a minimal mvalue.